# How to access data in a ViewModel of a UserControl from MainWindow

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have a UserControl (MVVM pattern) and a MainWindow. The UserControl Model get all Data and hold it, now i want to access this data from the MainWindow and bind it to a Control.

But how?

**EDIT**

UserControl.cs:

```
public UserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel.UserControlViewModel(
                       new Model.UserControlModel(this.facade));
}
```

the ViewModel.cs (from UserControl.cs)

```
public string Status
{
    get { return _model.Status; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _model.Status)
        {
            return;
        }
            _model.Status = value;
            base.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<StatusBarItem Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtStatus" Text="{Binding Path=???,
                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StatusBarItem>
```

So it's not so easy (maybe only for me ;) ) to set the DataContext for this

Comment: If your mainwindow hold the instance of UserControl, then you access all the members of ViewModel using DataContext property. If possible, put the requirements more clearly.

Comment: Can you please be more detailed?

Comment: The Data should be only updated by the UserControl, so i need to access this one instance of the ViewModel in the MainWindow. And this means, i couldn't set the DataContext in the MainView.

Comment: While I accept that the 'duplicate' question is *not* an exact duplicate, it *does* provide a good solution for you to pass your data using `delegate`s, which are kind of like custom events, but far more versatile. Furthermore, it also links to another question with another example of using `delegate`s. You can use `delegate`s to pass data to and from children and parents of any kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a MainWindowViewModel which holds the data like so:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel {
    public AllDataType AllData {get;set;}
}
```

Now you bind the MainWindows `DataContext` to this ViewModel and access the data:

```
<MainWindow>
    <ctrl:UserControl DataContext="{Binding AllData}"/>
    <AnotherControl DataContext="{Binding AllData}"/>
</MainWindow>
```